# Enter data into the database using PHP & Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to enter data into my database using PHP and Ajax.

I have a kind of user guestbook.

When I run my code it always jumps automatically to the else {} area, my text does not enter the database.

Could you guys help me please?

This is my Ajax Code

```
$("#addComment").on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var comment = $("#comment").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'add_comment.php?page=<?php echo $page; ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {comment: comment},
                success: function(data){
                    if (data == 1) {
                        loadData();
                        alert('Comment Submitted Successfully.');
                        $("#commentBox").trigger("reset");
                    }else {
                        alert("Comment Can't Submit.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
session_start();
include("assets/include/config.php");
require_once('assets/JBBCode/Parser.php');
$userid =  $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
echo $username;

$parser = new JBBCode\Parser();
$parser->addCodeDefinitionSet(new JBBCode\DefaultCodeDefinitionSet());
$error = false;
$comment = htmlentities($_POST['comment']);
$parser->parse($comment);
$bbcode =  $parser->getAsHtml();

if(strlen(trim($bbcode)) == 0){
        $error = true;
}

if($error == false){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO threadComments (subThreadsID, username, userid, threadContent) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->execute([$page, $username, $userid, $bbcode]);
}
```

and this is my HTML Code:

```
<form id="commentBox" action="subcomments.php?page=<?php echo $page ?>" method="POST">
        <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control" row="3" placeholder="Whats up.?" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="addComment" name="addComment" class="button-8">Comment</button>
    </form>
```

With the help of $_GET['page'] I tell the database which guestbook the comment should be added to.

Comment: (A) In the block `success: function(data){ ... }`, the ajax is expecting a return of data from the PHP script, but it appears that there is no correct data returned from your PHP (at least you need to echo "1" on success of the insert query so that data == 1 is true); (B) For the problem of failure to insert data, please check the values of $page, $username, $userid, $bbcode first

Comment: Thank you, I had not given a return value, now everything works as it should.